# Send Angular PUT request to Django using Django CSRF

Tags: django, angular, csrf, put

I am trying to update an entry into the django sqlite database using a put request. I am getting lots of 'forbidden' and '403' errors. I think this is because I can't find a way to attach the CSRF token from django.

I have seen some previous answers on here but they are from much older versions of Angular and I can't figure how to edit them to work with my code. (saying to put them in the module.config() block which I can't find).

Component HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm" (click)="update(project)">Update</button>
```

Component TS:

```
update(project: Project) {
    this.projectService.updateProject(project).subscribe();
}
```

Service TS:

```
updateProject(project: Project) {
    var httpudpdate: any = this.http.put('/ph/projects/'+project.id, project)
    return httpudpdate
}
```

I want the entry to be updated in the django but I am just getting errors, forbidden and 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import [HttpClientXsrfModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule) to your project, it will take care of reading the cookie and resending it as a custom header in every request.

The cookie and header names are not a standard, but rather a convention, so you can configure them if the default ones don't match your backend's ones.

As it happens, Django's cookie name and header name don't match Angular default ones so `HttpClientXsrfModule` has to be imported `withOptions` like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports:[..., HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName: 'csrftoken', headerName: 'X-CSRFToken' }), ...]
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Not fully sorted yet but seems to be on the right track!

Comment: If Django uses `XSRF-TOKEN` as cookie name and `X-XSRF-TOKEN` as header name, the module should work out of the box. If it doesn't, then import `HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName: 'djangoCookieName', headerName: 'djangoHeaderName' })` instead of just `HttpClientXsrfModule`

Comment: How would I check what defaults it uses?

Comment: According to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/csrf/ the header name is `X-CSRFToken` and the cookie name is `csrftoken`. You can verify at least the cookie name by looking at the network tab of your browser's dev tools

Comment: Looking at the network tab has just made me more confused as it appears that the cookie was already set for the put and its the same as the one in the get. It does say that only GET, POST, HEAD and OPTIONS are allowed though. Is there a way to make it allow PUT so I don't get the forbidden errors?

Comment: The cookie is set for a domain, whatever verb you use. Did you try to set the right values in the `HttpClientXsrfModule` import?

Comment: It shows me errors when I use this line: import { HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName: 'djangoCookieName', headerName: 'djangoHeaderName' }) } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: just `import { HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http'` like you did before. The `withOptions` goes into the `imports` section into your `AppModule` declaration

Comment: just tried this and still gives me error: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

Comment: in your network tab, do you see the cookie name? Is it `csrftoken`? also do you see the `X-CSRFToken` header in the outgoing requests?

Comment: The cookie value is: csrftoken=yv5iiZkhsn7eJQJ35sLpDDlDbb66Uy5f4vW6LvO2Sl2RMoGYYEDGf7Y5saxIH6mY; sessionid=kmciof5n8gsm1n9axar59u694uffynh6.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `HttpClientXsrfModule` import? (with `withOptions`)

Comment: Edit my question? I have the HttpClientXsrfModule imported at the top of app.module.ts and then put in the imports lower down (this bit has the 'withOptions' after it). Is there anywhere else to include it, does it need to be in my service.ts or component.ts at all?

Comment: No but I wanted to check the values you set in `cookieName` and `headerName`

Comment: I set them like you said with "cookieName: 'djangoCookieName'" and "headerName: 'djangoHeaderName'" (speechmarks there only because I don't know how to format as code like you're doing in the comments sorry haha

Comment: That was an example because I didn't know the real names back then! you need to set `cookieName` to `csrftoken` and `headerName` to `X-CSRFToken`

Comment: ah, that was the issue, it is working now, got some other issue to do with date now but the PUT request is working. Thank you very much for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Import `HttpClientXsrfModule` into your `app.module.ts`

```
<!-- app.module.ts -->
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports:[...,HttpClientXsrfModule,...]
```

Inject `HttpXsrfTokenExtractor` into your `service` or `HttpInterceptor` or file in which you want to use cookie.

```
constructor(private cookieExtractor:HttpXsrfTokenExtractor){}
```

To get the cookie, for example `xsrf` token

```
const xsrf: string = this.cookieExtractor.getToken();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to follow this but couldn't figure out how to implement it in my code? I have 2 methods in the class of my service, 1 returns all the 'projects' in my database and the other is to try and update as I showed in my original post. Where do I put the const and how would I attach that to the put request?

Comment: Where you're added headers to the `HTTP` request?

Comment: I have tried this but then the update button no longer sends a put request and I just get 'TypeError: "n is null"'. But this might be just cause I'm doing it wrong. Any help would be appreciated.